# How can I get the model formset to save for the correct person?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a few forms based off of people in the database. Basically at any given time, the users can be provided around 3 people to judge. The people are based off existing database instances and their scores are relationally linked to them via a primary key. Im trying to get these formsets to save for each person.

Models:

```
class couples(model.Model):

     dancer_fname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 First Name', max_length = 30)
     dancer_lname = models.CharField('Dancer 1 Last Name', max_length = 30)
     number = models.CharField('Number', max_length = 5)  


 class score(models.Model):

     couple_r1 = models.ForeignKey(couples, null=True, blank=True,  )
     number = models.CharField('Number', max_length = 5)

     judge = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

     style = models.FloatField(max_length = 10, null=True, blank=True )
     time = models.FloatField(max_length = 10, null=True, blank=True)
```

View:

```
    couplelist = couple.objects.all()

    FormSet = modelformset_factory(score, form = heatform)
    form = FormSet(queryset = score.objects.none())
```

Template:

```
   {% for X in couplelist %}
   {{form}}
   <input type = "hidden" value="X.number" name="number">
   <input type = "hidden" value="X.pk" name="pk">

   {% endfor %}
```

How can I get this to save so that each of the contestants get their scores, and number all on the correct row.